Using a gsub to split a name based on special characters
I have the following names which I am trying to change into first name, last name format.
myNamesDup
"Cross K / Cross M"  "Davis L/Harper C"  "Williams M / 
Brown M G" "Greening E-L / Roberts J" "Jones Williams D/Browning A"

What I am trying to achieve;

"K Cross/M Cross"  "L Davis/C Harper"  "M Williams/M G 
 Brown " "E-L Greening/j Roberts" "A Jones Williams/A Browning"

I have tried a few things for this unsuccessfully mainly due to special characters I think.
The closest I got to this is by using;

gsub("([A-Za-z]*) (.*)/(.*) ([A-Za-z]*)", "\\2 \\1/\\4 \\3", myNamesDup)

This gets me pretty close seems to fails on double barrel names and 2 first initials

You could try strsplit with sub like below
> unlist(lapply(strsplit(myNames, "/"), \(x) paste0(sub("(\\S+) (.*)", "\\2 \\1", trimws(x)), collapse = "/")))
[1] "K Cross/M Cross"             "L Davis/C Harper"
[3] "M Williams/M G Brown"        "E-L Greening/J Roberts"
[5] "Williams D Jones/A Browning"

or sub only like below
> gsub("(\\S+) (.*)\\s?/\\s?(\\S+) (.*)", "\\2 \\1/\\4 \\3", myNames)
[1] "K  Cross/M Cross"            "L Davis/C Harper"
[3] "M  Williams/M G Brown"       "E-L  Greening/J Roberts"
[5] "Williams D Jones/A Browning"


In the pattern that you tried, you have a lot of optional parts as [A-Za-z]* optionally repeats a char A-Za-z and .* matches any character 0+ times.
It would for example also match this string  /  as only the 2 spaces and the forward slash are required.
Matching names can be very difficult, but looking at the given formats there might be a pattern there keeping the capital letters with an optional part that is separated by either a space or dash at the end of a name.
([^\s/]+(?: [^\s/]+)*) ([A-Z](?:[ -][A-Z])*) */ *([^\s/]+(?: [^\s/]+)*?) ([A-Z](?:[ -][A-Z])*)\b

The regex in parts matches:

([^\s/]+(?: [^\s/]+)*)  Capture group 1, match 1+ non whitespace characters other than / and optionally repeat the same preceded by a space
([A-Z](?:[ -][A-Z])*) Capture group 2 Match an uppercase char A-Z and optionally repeat matching either a space or dash followed by an uppercase char A-Z
 */ * Match / between optional spaces
([^\s/]+(?: [^\s/]+)*?)  Capture group 3, same pattern as group 1, only the non capture group is repeated with non greedy quantifier
([A-Z](?:[ -][A-Z])*)\b Capture group 4, the same format as for group 2 followed by a word boundary to prevent a partial word match

The regex uses literal spaces, but you could also use for example \h to match horizontal whitespace characters.
See a regex demo and an R demo.
I think that for your last expected value you mean "D Jones Williams/A Browning" instead of "A Jones Williams/A Browning"
For example using gsub with perl = TRUE
myNamesDup <- c(
  "Cross K / Cross M",
  "Davis L/Harper C",
  "Williams M / Brown M G",
  "Greening E-L / Roberts J",
  "Jones Williams D/Browning A"
)

gsub(
  "([^\\s/]+(?: [^\\s/]+)*) ([A-Z](?:[ -][A-Z])*) */ *([^\\s/]+(?: [^\\s/]+)*?) ([A-Z](?:[ -][A-Z])*)\\b",
  "\\2 \\1/\\4 \\3",
  myNamesDup,
  perl = TRUE
)

Output
[1] "K Cross/M Cross"             "L Davis/C Harper"           
[3] "M Williams/M G Brown"        "E-L Greening/J Roberts"     
[5] "D Jones Williams/A Browning"

